# как сделать, чтобы рандомно загружать картинки из папки

Tags: javascript, css

Имею 9 блоков, куда нужно чтобы при перезагрузке фоновым изображением не повторяясь загружались картинки из папки. Подскажите, как можно реализовать это?

```
<div class="game">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
```

```
const block = document.querySelectorAll(".game div");
const imgCollection = [
  "assets/img/1.png",
  "assets/img/2.png",
  "assets/img/3.png",
  "assets/img/4.png",
  "assets/img/5.png",
  "assets/img/6.png",
  "assets/img/7.png",
  "assets/img/8.png",
  "assets/img/9.png",
];
reset.addEventListener("click", () => {
  location.reload();
      block.style.backgroundImage = 'url(x)';
      x = imgCollection[Math.floor(Math.random() * 9 + 1)];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Перемешать все элементы массива **до его использования**. Алгоритмов перемешивания много.
2. Дальше просто брать элементы по порядку.

Comment: Я новичок, подскажите, как можно это сделать? Я перемешиваю массив в x,но достать не получается, как это сделать?

Comment: Нет, вы не перемешиваете массив в x. Вы достаёте из массива значение по рандомному индексу. Перемешивания там нет

Comment: перемешал,  а как теперь сделать чтобы достать для всех блоков? ```reset.addEventListener("click", () => {
  location.reload();
      block.style.backgroundImage = 'url(x)';
      x=imgCollection.sort(()=>Math.random()-0.5);
});```

Comment: перечитайте мой ответ п.1.

Comment: и кстати, зачем там `location.reload();` -  это же перезагрузка страницы

Comment: location.reload(); делаю чтобы быстро сбросить все настройки, чтобы начать игру заново. Пытаюсь сделать, чтобы при каждой загрузке/перезагрузке страницы внутри блоков <div>  менялись фоновые изображения

Comment: так логика нарушена вкорне. получается страница перезагружается и всё. перемешивания не происходит...надо перемешивать всё, значит, после перезагрузки страницы, а по клику на кнопку просто перезагружать страницу

Comment: а разве не происходит последовательного выполнения команд? по клику на кнопку перезагружаю страницу, затем мешается массив , и заполняются блоки картинками?```reset.addEventListener("click", () => {   location.reload();  x=imgCollection.sort(()=>Math.random()-0.5);} ``` но я не знаю как сделать чтобы эти блоки заполнились. я новичок, пытаюсь разобраться

Comment: да, исполнение последовательное......но скрипт загружается заново после обновления страницы и он нигде не хранит у себя знания о том, что после перезагрузки надо что-то выполнять......поэтому существует событие и подписка на событие перезагрузки страницы как минимум. Так что тут страница просто перезагрузится и всё